# Solve the system..

Tags: linear-algebra

> Solve the system
>
> $4x_1 - 5x_2 + 2x_3 + 2x_4 = 1$
>
> $-x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 + 3x_4 = 2$
>
> $3x_1 -4x_2 + 4x_3 + 5x_4 = 3$
>
> $3x_1 - 3x_2 -6x_3 - 9x_4 = -6$
>
> $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\\\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\\\end{bmatrix} s + \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\\\end{bmatrix} t$

so... I threw this horrid system of equations into a augmented matrix and solved the RREF form to get

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-12&-17&-11\\0&1&-10&-14&-9\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

but I'm not sure now how to solve for the three vectors. (also are these vectors I'm filling out or are these $4 \times 1$ matrixes??

Comment: Good, you've got it in RREF.  Now what do you think you should do?

Comment: Try to solve for $x_1, x_2 , x_3,  x_4$ for each row?

Comment: The columns with out the 1 are the "free variable" columns right?

Comment: How about we set some of the $x_i$ equal to a free variable?  No -- it's the columns *without* a pivot.  So it'll be your third and fourth columns (the last is of course a little different because this is an augmented matrix).

Comment: so columns $x_3, x_4, x_5$ are the free variables

Comment: What's $x_5$?  I don't see an $x_5$ in the question.  Note that your matrix should really look like $$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & 0 & 12 & 17 & 11 \\ 0 & 1 & -10 & -14 & -9 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: oh I guess just $x_3, x_4$ I guess $x_5$ = b vector

Comment: There is no $x_5$.  The last column your $b$ vector.  This is a matrix equation of the type $Ax=b$, not the $Ax=0$ ones you were doing before.

Comment: @Shammy There are 2 free variable columns in the resulting Guass-Jordan form matrix. The final column is the "solution vector" of the system. So you'll end up with 2 free variables of the 4 equations in 4 unknowns.

Comment: So what do $x_1$ and $x_2$ equal once you've defined your free variables?

Comment: @Bye_World Ok, so its not a "homogeneous" eqn thing or whattver then right

Comment: Right.  This one is *non*-homogeneous.

Comment: ok so then $x_1 = -12x_2  -17x_3 - 11$ ?

Comment: Well Bernard just answered my last question to you, but hopefully with that you can now find the solution yourself.  **Edit:** No.  The first row of your augmented matrix says $x_1+12x_3+17x_4=11$, so moving everything to the right except $x_1$ we get $x_1 = -12x_3-17x_4+11$.

Comment: Why does he think the 11 is positive

Comment: oh wait , hes right that last column i keep forgettting is a different vector

Comment: so now i know $x_1 = -12x_3 -17x_4 + 11$ and $x_2 = 10x_3  + 14x_4 - 9$

Comment: Ok, i get confused on the parameter part with $s$ and $t$ . should it now be like $\begin{bmatrix}-12\\10\\s\\t\end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}-17\\14\\s\\t\end{bmatrix}s$ + $\begin{bmatrix}11\\-9\\s\\t\end{bmatrix}t$ ?

Comment: @Shammy You should check your reduced form carefully. Either you have a typo in the original equations or the reduced form, or your reduced form is wrong.

Comment: Nope.  Start with $\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4} = \pmatrix{-12s-17t+11 \\ 10s+14t-9 \\ s \\ t}$.  Then just split this into separate columns $$\pmatrix{-12s \\ 10s \\ s \\ 0}+\pmatrix{-17t \\ 14t \\ 0 \\ t} + \pmatrix{11 \\ -9 \\ 0 \\ 0}=\pmatrix{-12 \\ 10 \\ 1 \\ 0}s+\pmatrix{-17 \\ 14 \\ 0 \\ 1}t + \pmatrix{11 \\ -9 \\ 0 \\ 0}$$

Comment: @almagest There were'nt negatives in the first row, fixed it. thanks for noticing

Answer (score 3):

The row reduced form says
\begin{align*}
x_1 & =12x_3+17x_4-11,\\
x_2 & =10x_3+14x_4-9.
\end{align*}
In other words, setting $x_3=s$, $x_4=t$, the solutions can be written as
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}12\\10\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}s+\begin{bmatrix}17\\14\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}t\,- \begin{bmatrix}11\\ 9\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: Ok, i get confused on the parameter part with $s$ and $t$ . should it now be like $\begin{bmatrix}-12\\10\\s\\t\end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}-17\\14\\s\\t\end{bmatrix}s$ + $\begin{bmatrix}11\\-9\\s\\t\end{bmatrix}t$ ?

Comment: Am I incorrect?

Comment: The only problem is that the OPs reduced form does not match his original equations.

Comment: my RREF is incorrect? @almagest

Comment: @almagest good catch, edited it. was a typo when i typed in the RREF form

Comment: @Shammy: I've added  the solution in the form you want.

Comment: My RREF is form is incorrect, I forgot that i was dividing Row 1s, last 3 entries by a negative. I have now fixed it to the correct form

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: It seems to me it implicitly answers the question. What  did I miss?

Comment: @The GreatDuck:The row reduced form translates *at once* into parametrisation. It's the opportunity for the O.P. to test if he/she has understood.

Comment: I've added a detail: is it clear enough now?

Answer (score 1):

When you have free variables, then you can express the non-free variables in terms of them.

So you will get some equation formed by the rows in RREF for instance:

$x_1 - 2x_3 = 3$

$x_2 + x_3 = 1$

Now solve for x1 and x2...

$x_1 = 3 + 2x_3$

$x_2 = 1 - x_3$

So now the vector $<x_1,x_2,x_3> = <3+2x_3,1-x_3,x_3> = <3,1,0> + <2,-1,1>x_3$

Does the process make sense to you now?

You need to remember that each row of an augmented matrix is an equality relation. So when you place it into row reduced echelon form, you recieve a series of identities. Each row as you read down will give the identity for that index. (Row 1 gives the expression you write in place of x1, row 2 for x2, etc.). Empty rows mean that the variable is free. This is assuming that the matrix is square. If it is not square then variables that are unlisted are free. I am sure you can read it close enough to understand. Just solve for each variable such that the number of variables in the relationship has been limited.

You also asked if this was vectors or matrices. Sorry kid... I hate to break it to ya. Vectors *are* matrices. An augmented matrix is just a way of writing the matrix equation Ax = b. Nothing explicitly states that x must be a vector. Thats just the convention. Vectors are matrices with one column.

In fact, matrix multiplication is defined as special vector multiplication.

Let b1... bn be vectors:

A[b1, b2, b3, bn] = [Ab1, Ab2, Ab3... Abn]

As you can see, this makes matrix multiplication the same as vector multiplication.

Comment: OK.  No worries.